# Removing new line characters from NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, string

I have a `NSString` like this:

```
Hello 
World
of
Twitter
Lets See this
>
```

I want to transform it to:

> Hello World of Twitter Lets See this >

How can I do this? I'm using Objective-C on an iPhone.

Comment: downvoted because you still can't accept an answer...

Comment: ramesh, accept the answer maybe? people helped u and least u could do is accept their correct and awesome answer.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Split the string into components and join them by space:

```
NSString *newString = [[myString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

Comment: -stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet will remove characters only from the beginning and the end of the string

Comment: okay thats the point i have new line characters all over the place

Comment: Ah my bad, updated the example to split the string and join it by putting a space in instead of the newline characters.

Comment: Wow, missed this method in NSArray

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to spot as it's on NSArray. Double checked now and noticed that it's actually linked from the API docs to componentsSeparatedByString on NSString.

Comment: Works great! Much better than searching and replacing characters.

Comment: Perhaps say why this is better than than `stringByReplacing` in the answer, please?

Comment: This way will work but it creates an array that isn't needed. It is also slightly less clear what is happening.

Comment: This works better than `stringByReplacing` if you need to handle all types of newline characters.

Comment: Thnaks a lot for help

Comment: This helped me in Marquee lable. Thnaks a lot

Answer (score 91):

Splitting the string into components and rejoining them is a very long-winded way to do this.  I too use the same method Paul mentioned. You can replace any string occurrences.  Further to what Paul said you can replace new line characters with spaces like this:

```
myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];
```

Comment: This answer is the best one as it makes it very clear what is happening (all newline characters are being replaced by spaces) and doesn't require the creation of an extraneous array. y ramesh rao, You really should accept the answer that best solves the problem to encourage people to continue answering your questions.

Comment: This won't necessarily do the job—at the very least you'd probably want to include \r as well. `[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]` is "A character set containing the newline characters (U+000A–U+000D, U+0085)" so it's much more thorough. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: I agree with @robotspacer actually. If you require coverage of *all* newline characters then the `NSCharacterSet` route is the way to go. My solution still removes `U+000A` and shows usage of `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` at least so it's worth keeping here.

Comment: Blame our forefathers for creating so many newline characters. So dumb.

Answer (score 9):

I'm using

```
[...]
myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n\n" withString:@"\n"];
[...]
```

/Paul

Answer (score 5):

My case also contains `\r`, including `\n`, `[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]` does not work, instead, by using

```
htmlContent = [htmlContent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[\r\n]"
                                                     withString:@""
                                                        options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                          range:NSMakeRange(0, htmlContent.length)];
```

solved my problem.

Btw, `\\s` will remove all white spaces, which is not expected.

Answer (score 4):

Providing a Swift 3.0 version of @hallski 's answer here:

```
self.content = self.content.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines).joined(separator: " ")
```

Providing a Swift 3.0 version of @Kjuly 's answer here (Note it replaces any number of new lines with just one \n. I would prefer to not use regular express if someone can point me a better way):

```
self.content = self.content.replacingOccurrences(of: "[\r\\n]+", with: "\n", options: .regularExpression, range: Range(uncheckedBounds: (lower: self.content.startIndex, upper: self.content.endIndex)));
```