# remove "\n" from NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

My json is returning this :

> address = "129 City Road
>
> \nShoreditch
>
> \nLondon EC1V 1JB";

I want to remove the "\n". Because I want to display it in one line.

I tried following:

```
NSString * newReplacedString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];

NSString * newReplacedString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

Both result same:

**Result**

> 900 N Michigan Avenue
>
> Chicago
>
> Illinois 60611

If I tried this

```
NSString *s = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\\n"];
```

**Result**

> 900 N Michigan Avenue
>
> \nChicago
>
> \nIllinois 60611

Please suggest.

Comment: what is your question..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9431312/653513

Comment: can you post the json string from which you want to remove \n,in above post thier are two address.

NSString * newReplacedString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];

this code is not working for you?

Comment: I want to remove "\n" from the string

Answer (score 21):

Try it :

```
NSString *address = @"129 City Road \nShoreditch \nLondon EC1V 1JB";    
address = [address stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
address = [address stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

This worked and i got the output like :

```
129 City Road Shoreditch London EC1V 1JB
```

Comment: As you can see in the question a `\n` is displayed, this make is clear that the string is not containing `\n` but `\\n`

Comment: @rckoenes : He has given his json string. and the string contains '\n' and not '\\n' .

Comment: no is output contains `\n` which means that it is `\\n` because otherwise the `\n` would not be printed and just replaces with a new line.

Comment: thanks. upvoted. I had a situation where I had to remove \r\n before it would remove the  line.

Answer (score 16):

It looks like the `\n` is a literally in you string and not as a newline character, then you need to escape the `\`, like `\\n`:

```
NSString * newReplacedString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@""];

NSString * newReplacedString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 9):

```
NSString *newString = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r\n" withString:@""];
```

For those who may be looking for the answer. Try the above once. It worked for me.

Comment: I just want to remove "\n" from the following string but its not working for this string :   "\uD83D\uDE00\n\n--\nAckroyd stevr\n"                                                  Any words on this case ?

Answer (score 3):

Priyanka
Use Following code to remove new lines.

```
-(NSString *)stringByRemovingNewLinesAndWhitespace {

// Pool
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

// Strange New lines:
//  Next Line, U+0085
//  Form Feed, U+000C
//  Line Separator, U+2028
//  Paragraph Separator, U+2029

// Scanner
NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:self];
[scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];
NSMutableString *result = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSString *temp;
NSCharacterSet *newLineAndWhitespaceCharacters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:
                                                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@" \t\n\r%C%C%C%C", 0x0085, 0x000C, 0x2028, 0x2029]];
// Scan
while (![scanner isAtEnd]) {

    // Get non new line or whitespace characters
    temp = nil;
    [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:newLineAndWhitespaceCharacters intoString:&temp];
    if (temp) [result appendString:temp];

    // Replace with a space
    if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:newLineAndWhitespaceCharacters intoString:NULL]) {
        if (result.length > 0 && ![scanner isAtEnd]) // Dont append space to beginning or end of result
            [result appendString:@" "];
    }

}

// Cleanup
[scanner release];

// Return
NSString *retString = [[NSString stringWithString:result] retain];
[result release];

// Drain
[pool drain];

// Return
return [retString autorelease];
```

}

Comment: then use 

str= [str stringByRemovingNewLinesAndWhitespace];

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *data= [str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove "\n" do the following

```
//Str contains your json value
NSString *str;
NSString *newString = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *newString = [[myString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

[Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807803/removing-new-line-characters-from-nsstring) .Check the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
NSString *s = [@"900 N Michigan \nAvenue \nChicago \nIllinois 60611" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@", s); //900 N Michigan Avenue Chicago Illinois 60611
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working

```
NSString *address = @"129 City Road"
    "\nShoreditch"
    "\nLondon EC1V 1JB";

    address = [address stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"address--%@",address);
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned  `[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""]` doesnt work..

Have you tried the "\r"

```
 [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@""]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2.2: let newWord = address.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "")